# Should I scan and store a customers I.D. card and fingerprint in a BLOB for every transaction?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, blob, informix

[image]

I have a pawnshop app written with isql 7.32.  A new law now requires that the customer's I.D. and a Fingerprint be recorded on the original printed ticket every time a loan or buy transaction is performed, and that these tickets must be kept for 5 years.

On average, my pawnshops process over 6,000 transactions per year, so 5 years worth can easily run over 30,000 transactions!.. This implies a huge increase in storage consumption if I were to store the images for each transaction and would like to know if queries and updates would significantly take longer.

Also, I would imagine that these images are BLOB's (BYTE) datatypes, in which each image is stored externally from the database in a separate file, thus the directory containing them would grow to tens of thousands of files, is this a problem?

Up to now, I've only been storing one I.D. and Fingerprint per customer when they are added for the first time into the customer master table.

Would it be better to manually copy the I.D. and Fingerprint on to the rear side of pawn and buy tickets once they have been printed, but continue to store one I.D. and one fingerprint per customers on the customers master table for customer authentication purposes?

It is my understanding that with ISQL's "Perform" screens, when a query is performed, the BLOBs are not accessed during the query, rather they are accessed when users choose to see them with Perform's View command?

How should I design this table to ensure performance?

EDIT: The other question to ask is: Is there really a need to access these images on a regular basis?.. NO!.. The reason the Law is requiring it is for Law Enforcement to have more information available in identifying someone who has stolen the property and pawned or sold it to the pawnshop, so anyway, they're going to request to see the item(s), their associated printed document(s), and their corresponding I.D. and Fingerprint.. What Law Enforcement will usually ask the pawnshop owner is if any reported stolen items matching a similar description are or were at the pawnshop because in most cases, the perpetrator is unknown. Thus, a query by the item(s) description is performed, and any transactions that contain similar desired items, Law Enforcement will want to see the item(s) and review the original printed transaction document to see who done it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IANAL

You need to consult with the legal people to decide whether it is sufficient to store the image scanned when the person first comes into the store, or whether you need to store a new image each time a person makes a transaction.  Either system works technically; the legal story may be quite different.

My suspicion is that you will need to take an image each time that a customer comes in.  The police might be interested if the customer's identification papers (images) change over time other than simple licence renewals.

---

There are various issues that you'll have to deal with.

#### Blob storage

- Informix Standard Engine (SE) has no support for BYTE or TEXT (or BLOB or CLOB) blobs.
- Informix Dynamic Server (IDS) stores BYTE or TEXT blobs either 'IN TABLE' in the same dbspace(s) as the main data for the table, but on separate pages from the regular data in the rows, or in a blobspace specifically created for storing blobs.  In either case, the regular data for the rows contains a blob descriptor which shows where the blob is actually stored.
- IDS stores BLOB and CLOB 'smart blobs' in a smart blobspace specifically created for storing blobs.  Again, a descriptor is stored in the row along with the regular data.
- In no case does IDS store blobs 'loose' in the file system.  They are stored in transactionally managed disk space reserved for the DBMS.
- IDS has a Virtual Table Interface (VTI) that could be used to access files from the file system if you so chose.

The actual volume of data depends on the resolution of the images you need to store.  The good news is that disk space is pretty cheap these days.  Let's suppose you're saving high-resolution images of 3 MiB each.  If you need to store 30,000 of those, you need about 100 GiB of disk space.  Although you probably can still buy smaller disks (I assume), you won't be hard pushed to find disks in the multiple hundreds of GiB available for use.  So, I don't see storage as a major problem.  And the volume does not pose workload limitations.  If it was 30,000 per day, then we'd need to discuss the issues, but it still probably wouldn't be a huge problem.

#### User interface

ISQL is probably not the tool of choice if you need to be able display scans.  You might be able to get the system to work OK for data entry, and maybe the identity information can be incorporated into report (tickets) etc.  Nevertheless, it is probably not going to be trivial.

I'm not a UI developer; I work with CLI programs and down in the bowels of the DBMS.  I'm not sure what to advise as the front-end.  I'd probably suggest looking at Genero (sold by IBM and developed by [FourJs](http://www.4js.com/)).

#### Table design

In terms of table design, I'd have one a separate table from the existing tables to store the images.  It would contain a SERIAL column to give an image number, and you'd add foreign key image number column to the relevant existing tables.  The image table would also hold the blob with the image, and probably some metadata about the image (date and time, maybe customer ID, maybe scanning device ID).  This allows flexibility to handle whatever the legal people say is necessary.  You can reused an ID number if you don't have to take the image each time; you can still store the information if you do.  You will still benefit from having a separate table to hold the data (except, perhaps, from the perspective of the ISQL UI - but that becomes another reason to worry about the use of ISQL).  One benefit is that if you don't want to see the images, you can simply leave the image table out of the query; you won't accidentally get the images selected if you run a 'SELECT *' query.

#### Timestamped record keeping

I'm not clear whether the law requires your pawnshop owners to keep a copy of the original ticket print out as of the time of the transaction or whether an electronic copy that can be regenerated is sufficient.  You might need to consider time stamping the records - see [PublicTimeStamp.org](http://www.publictimestamp.org/) for one possible way of doing that.  This would give you a reasonably simple means of independently recording that the electronic document was created at a specific time.

Comment: IANAL: Storing digitized images for each transaction is not a legal requirement, having a copy of the I.D. along with a Fingerprint on original part of the 3-ply pawn or buy ticket is required! Police Investigators goal is to examine documents related to what they're searching for, and although not required by Law, I would think that an image of the merchandise would be desireable!.. BLOB STORAGE: I would imagine that 100K per image would be sufficient? Is it more advantageous to use VTI?.. UI: ISQL's "Perform" provides the "View" command for viewing images with choice of external viewer...

Comment: (Continued) TABLE DESIGN: If I were to store images for each transaction, I would try, if possible, to store them externally from the database and have a column pointing to the external file? However, there is no real need for storing the image on the db, maybe just the I.D. card from when the customer was first added into the system, for authentication purposes.. TIMESTAMPED RECORD KEEPING: I am currently time-stamping each transaction with a DATETIME column and it is also printed on each ticket.. MY CONCLUSION: No advantage in storing I'D./Fingerprint for each trany, but merchandise, yes!

Comment: (CONTINUED) unless a theft, fire or flood were to destroy or make unavailable the printed tickets containing a copy of the customers I.D. and original fingerprint.. Maybe a separate document storage app would be desirable to digitize and store each original ticket?

Answer (score 0):

I would store the images as files on the hard disk and save the filename to the database.  The only downside is that if you are using something like Crystal Reports for reporting that knows how to display the pictures directly from the database then you won't be able to use that feature.

I'm guessing you really don't need to do any reporting on these images though... you just need to be able to give the police the picture of a thumbprint if necessary.  This is going to be much easier to do if you can just look up the persons thumbprint filename and then email it to the police.  It will be more work to get at the data in BLOB format.  Not a huge issue, but just another reason not to store in the database imo.

So this seems like a no brainer to me as far as whether to keep them in the database as BLOB's or just save them as picture files and store the filename.  Let me know if I'm missing anything though and I'll try to give a better answer.

Comment: Informix IDS, "Informix Dynamic Server", its RDBMS engine, in combination with ISQL's "Perform" (a CRUD screen client) provides a mechanism for displaying BYTE datatypes, which are stored externally from the RDBMS in any image file format. I think the mechanism goes as follows: a BYTE column's attribute in the "Perform" screen is PROGRAM = "program name", where program name is the name of any executable program used to display images and the BYTE datatype in the IDS table points to the external file. Now, I don't know what performance impact there is when thousands of external files exist?

Answer (score 0):

Frank, why don't you test it out?  You may have the expertise to do it yourself, or if not it shouldn't be too big a project to get someone to help you with without spending too much money.

You just need a script to take one of the pics (or one that will be similar if you don't have one yet) and insert it into a blob field for 10,000 (or however many you want to test) records.

As for designing the tables, here's my suggestion:  You want to partition vertically so so it's easier to partition horizontially.  Meaning, put the blob in a table by itself (or with other fields that are *only* specific to the picture... like maybe a date when it was taken) with an id linking it to other data.  Then every so often you can backup what's in that table and then truncate older records.  All that matters is that you can restore that data if you need to so if it is slowing the system down then there's no reason to leave it there.